# Qt : Fit width of TableView to width of content

Tags: qt, pyside, qtableview

I have a window that contains a `QTableView` which **columns are adjusted to content** and are **fixed in width**. The `QTableView` is nested within a `QWidget` that in turn is nested within a `QScrollArea` that in turn is nested within a **tabbed** `QMdiArea` which is the `centralWidget` of a `QMainWindow`.

When the `QScrollArea` is shown, the `QTableView` has extra space to the right of the last column that I want to be removed :

[image: Screenshot of TableView]

I want the `QTableView` to fit the exact width of the columns (i.e. no extra space after the rightmost column).

I tried to use `tableView.setFixedWidth(desired_width)` but then the only way it could work was to iterate over all the columns and get their widths and sum them up together and add the `verticalHeader` width and the scroll-bars width and pass it as the `desired_width`.

It does work this way but it seems to be very complex for such an obvious requirement : I think a lot of program developers want their tables' width to fit the columns' width and this is what makes me wonder that maybe there is a method that does that automatically without the extra calculations and that I'm unaware of.

So my question is : is there a simpler way to achieve the same result ?

Here is my code for reference :

The code for the `t_main` module responsible for creating the `QMainWindow` :

```
import sys
import t_wdw
from PySide import QtGui

class Main_Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main_Window,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar()
        # Defines QActions for menu
        self.new_window=QtGui.QAction("&Window alpha",self)
        self.new_window.triggered.connect(self.open_window)
        # Creates the menu
        self.menu_bar=self.menuBar()
        self.menu1=self.menu_bar.addMenu('&Menu 1')
        self.menu1.addAction(self.new_window)
        # Creates a QMdiArea to manage all windows.
        self.wmanager=QtGui.QMdiArea()
        self.wmanager.setViewMode(QtGui.QMdiArea.TabbedView)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.wmanager)
        self.showMaximized()

    # Opens the new window that holds the QTableView
    def open_window(self):
        t_wdw.launch_window()
        t_wdw.window_alpha=self.wmanager.addSubWindow(t_wdw.window)
        t_wdw.window_alpha.show()

def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_wdw=Main_Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The code for `t_wdw` module that is responsible for creating the `SubWindow` with the `QTableView`.

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

def launch_window():
    global window
    # Creates a new window
    window=QtGui.QScrollArea()
    window1=QtGui.QWidget()
    row=0
    data=[["VH"+str(row+i),1,2,3] for i in range(20)]
    headers=["HH1","HH2","HH3"]
    # Creates a table view with columns resized to fit the content.
    model=my_table(data,headers)
    tableView=QtGui.QTableView()
    tableView.setModel(model)
    tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
    # Fixes the width of columns and the height of rows.
    tableView.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)
    tableView.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)

    """
    Here is the solution I resorted to to fix the tableView width 
    equal to its content and that I want to make simpler
    """
    vhwidth=tableView.verticalHeader().width()
    desired_width=QtGui.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent*2+vhwidth+1
    for i in range(len(headers)):
        desired_width+=tableView.columnWidth(i)
    tableView.setFixedWidth(desired_width)

    """
    Sets the layouts and widgets using a QHBoxLayout because
    I want the QTableView to be centered on the window
    and more widgets and layouts are to be added later.
    """

    window1.main_layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    window1.main_layout.addStretch(0)
    window1.main_layout.addWidget(tableView)
    window1.main_layout.addStretch(0)
    window.setLayout(window1.main_layout)
    window.setWidget(window1)

class my_table(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self,data,headers,parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.__data=data
        self.__headers=headers

    def rowCount(self,parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self,parent):
        return len(self.__headers)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            return self.__data[row][column+1]

    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self.__headers[section]
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return self.__data[section][0]
```

An extra question for those who read the code : Why do I need to multiply `PM_ScrollBarExtent` by 2 to get the correct result ?

P.S : I'm using PySide 1.2.1 but answers in PyQt or C++ are fine.

Comment: You can use something like `tableView.visualRect(model.index(0, model.columnCount() - 1)).right()` instead of iterating over all columns.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work, the visualRect returns (0,0,0,0).

Comment: Well I managed to use `tableView.horizontalHeader().length()` instead to avoid iterating but I still needed to sum it up with `tableView.verticalHeader().width()` and `PM_ScrollBarExtent*2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of things about your width calcualtion that are wrong.

Firstly, you attempt to use `QtGui.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent` to get the width of the vertical scrollbar - but that is a constant, not a property. Instead, you need to use [QStyle.pixelMetric](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#pixelMetric):

```
tableView.style().pixelMetric(QtGui.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent)
```

Secondly, you do not take into account the width of the tableview frame, which can be calculated like this:

```
tableView.frameWidth() * 2
```

Putting these values together with the dimensions of the headers, the final calculation should be:

```
vwidth = tableView.verticalHeader().width()
hwidth = tableView.horizontalHeader().length()
swidth = tableView.style().pixelMetric(QtGui.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent)
fwidth = tableView.frameWidth() * 2

tableView.setFixedWidth(vwidth + hwidth + swidth + fwidth)
```

This should leave exactly the space needed for the vertical scrollbar.

PS:

Since you're setting a fixed width for the tableview, you could also get rid of the horizontal scrollbar, which is redundant:

```
tableView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I eventually ended up by using `tableView.horizontalHeader().length()` and `tableView.verticalHeader().width()` as I said in the comments and I forgot to say but I replaced `QtGui.QStyle.PM_ScrollBarExtent` by `tableView.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width()`. Now I'm not sure which one is more correct, `sizeHint()` or your method ? But I was always still adding 1 pixel to get the appropriate result and I guess now, thanks to your answer, that this pixel was accounting for `tableView.frameWidth() * 2 `. So sad there isn't a simpler method. Thank you again.

Comment: @ekhumoro This is really helpful. Strangely, I'm still left needing to add 6 pixels to get an exact fit. I thought this might be due to pixels added by lines between columns, but it is 6 pixels regardless of number of columns displayed. For now I just add it as a fudge factor, but prefer not to...

Comment: @neuronet. Hard to say without seeing actual code. Please start a new question, and include a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem. You should probably say what platform you're on, as well.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960006/in-qdialog-resize-window-to-contain-all-columns-of-qtableview

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can do something like this:

```
tableview->resizeColumnsToContents();

QHeaderView* header = tableview->horizontalHeader();
header->setStretchLastSection(true);
tablewview->setHorizontalHeader(header);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but `setStretchLastSection` just stretches the last column to fill the remaining space in the `tableView` while I'm trying to do the opposite which is to shrink the `tableView` to the width of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Qt 5.2 you can use the following:

```
view->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow);
```

or

```
view->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents);
```

Comment: These made no difference for me.